# Hide Keyboard when android:editable = "false"

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have two `EditText` fields, one that is editable and one that is read-only by using both

```
android:editable="false" and android:inputType="none".
```

If I tap on the read-only `EditText` first then it works as intened which is no keyboard and no data entry.

If I first select the first `EditText` field that is read/write then the keyboard pops up and data can be entered BUT if I then tap on the Read Only `EditText` the soft keyboard then switches to the alpha keyboard although no data can be entered.

I would like the ReadOnly `EditText` to NEVER show a keyboard since it is ReadOnly.

To Reiterate - If there is no keyboard displayed then ReadOnly `EditText` doesn't display a keyboard BUT if a keyboard is open the ReadOnly `EditText` shows the alpha keyboard. This is confusing to the user and I would like to prevent ReadOnly `EditText` from showing any keyboard ever. Not sure if this is an Android Layout problem/solution or an Android Java problem/solution so I am tagging this post under just Android.

Answer (score 1):

If EditText is uneditable why not use textview instead of textview and set its style/bg as edit text, please go through one of my post.

[layout having disabled edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725107/layout-having-disabled-edit-text/8725289#8725289)

Comment: A Perfect solution, wish I would have known about this before I started because I uncovered the 'bug' during final beta testing and now will make a bunch of changes to 8 apps.  Thank-you for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Remove below line from your XML file:-

```
android:editable="false"
android:inputType="none"
```

and add the below line to your java file onCreate method:-

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

After above changes the first time keyboard is hidden and if u click on the edittext at that time the keyboard is shown.

Comment: I have two kinds of EditText 1. Editable and 2. Not Editable.  I am not sure how your solution detects the Not Editable ones.  I would really like the soft keyboard to hide itself if it is open when a user taps on the Not Editable EditText.  If there is no soft keyboard then it does not popup when the user taps on the Not Editable EditText but if the soft keyboard is open from a previous entry then when a user taps on the Not Editable EditText the soft keyoard changes to the alpho view and does not nllow data entry.  If Android can detect the tap then there should be a way to hide the keyboard